# Has and belongs to many - check additional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an User and Employer models. An User can have multiple Employers and vise versa and there is also a flag indicating if their relationship is active:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employers

end

class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

and a migration:

```
class CreateUserEmployers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users_companies do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :employer_id
      t.boolean :is_active
    end
  end
end
```

If I have an User and one of their employers

```
test1 = User.find(1).employers.first
```

how do I check if an `User's` relationship with that `Employer` is active (the field `is_active` in `users_employers` table)?

Comment: You must use a Join Model and a has_many through.  Then write a migration to add the is_active boolean field to your join table.  HABTM in Rails is very limited and I would avoid using them because you seem to always run into limitations at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):

> A has_and_belongs_to_many association creates a direct many-to-many connection with another model, with no intervening model.

If you want to add the `is_active` boolean field (or any other attributes), I suggest you use the [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association. You would need to create a third model (i.e. `UserEmployer`, `EmployerUser`, or something else altogether) and your associations would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employers, through: :user_employers
  has_many :user_employers
end

class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :user_employers
  has_many :user_employers
end

class UserEmployer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :employer
end
```

Comment: Based on what you want (with using the additional `is_active` attribute) you'd need to use the `has_many :through` association. I don't think it's possible to accomplish this easily with the HABTM association, if at all. You'll need to create that third model and update the associations. If you're worried about existing records, you could write a rake task to convert all the existing associations to the newly created `has_many :through` associations.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "is_active" ? what is it for? is that mean "yes this user has employer" or vice versa? if so, you can define an "is_active" method in your 3rd model (takes an additional arg. for employer id or object itself) and check if that user/employer has employer/user. But the architecture seems kind a wrong

Comment: It's just my custom field, whatever it does. I might've given it a different name.